# Count documents in several collections simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to count the amount of documents in three separate MongoDB collections simultaneously. What I have right now works but is slow. Can anyone please help me to optimize it?

```
app.post('/fetch-numbers',(req, res) => {
  let numbers = {};
  Clinic.countDocuments({})
  .then(clinicCount => {
    numbers.clinicCount = clinicCount;
    Dentist.countDocuments({})
    .then(dentistCount => {
      numbers.dentistCount = dentistCount;
      Booking.countDocuments({})
      .then(bookingCount => {
        numbers.bookingCount = bookingCount;
        res.json(numbers)
      })
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.json(err)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your queries are independent, you can run them all in parallel with `promise.all()`, code will look like:

```
app.post('/fetch-numbers', async (req, res) => {
    Promise.all([
        Clinic.countDocuments({}),
        Dentist.countDocuments({}),
        Booking.countDocuments({})
    ])
    .then((docCounts) => {
        const numbers = docCounts.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        res.json(numbers);
    })
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
    const numbers = docCounts.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    res.json(numbers);
});
```

You can further make it more readable by using `async-await` with `Promise.all()`, eg:

```
app.post('/fetch-numbers', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const docCounts = await Promise.all([
            Clinic.countDocuments({}),
            Dentist.countDocuments({}),
            Booking.countDocuments({})
        ]);
        const numbers = docCounts.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        res.json(numbers);
    } catch(err) {
        res.json(err);
    }
});
```

You can read more here
[Promise.all()](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/promise-all-in-javascript-with-example-6c8c5aea3e32/), [async-await](https://javascript.info/async-await) and [async-await with Promise.all()](https://www.taniarascia.com/promise-all-with-async-await/)